# App Store screenshot auto scroll effect

Tags: ios

In the Appstore screen shots section, just wondering how would someone implement the way Apple automatically scrolls down right at the screen shot edges when a user starts paging the screenshots horizontally?

Did they use animation?  How would you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very legitimate question, i know it may not fit guide lines but the AppStore is a place ALL iOS developer will go to and see.  This will get them to see how this is done if they are wondering.  Not sure why these people think voting down questions that they think are not legit will give them browny points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably use the UIScrollView method:

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or the UIScrollView method:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

When the horizontal scroll view's delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

gets called, figure out the rect or point you want, and then do:

```
[theVerticalScrollView scrollRectToVisible:theRectYouWant animated:YES];
```

or

```
[theVerticalScrollView setContentOffset:thePointYouWant animated:YES];
```